# Is it supported to use CooperativeStickyAssignor for kafka cluster version 2.2.1?

Tags: apache-kafka, rebalancing

Kafka broker cluster version is 2.2.1. Client version is 2.7.1. There is CooperativeStickyAssignor in kafka client lib. Is it supported to use CooperativeStickyAssignor to consume from a 2.2.1 broker cluster?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It is better to use it with 3.4.1 due to the two major bugs

- https://issues.apache.org/jira/browse/KAFKA-14639
- https://issues.apache.org/jira/browse/KAFKA-13419